# SLD file Style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, layers, sld

When I want to load sld file in geoserver appears this error:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I saw that is something about https.

This is the url:

https://geo.gob.bo/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&VERSION=1.3.0&SLD_VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&CRS=EPSG:3857&SLD=https://geo.gob.bo/mapfishapp/ws/sld/geodoc439edd21e7b1c8ea5a24f35116aef572.sld&LAYER=AGETIC:estado_entidades2017&FORMAT=image/png&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels:on;fontAntiAliasing:true&SCALE=10000

Comment: The Java version that you use for runnign GeoServer does not trust the certificate of the server at geo.gob.bo which seems to be the same server that you use for running GeoServer. Add the required certificates into the Java keystore. How it is done is not related to GIS.